# HTTP Error 404.11 Not Found: double escape sequence

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, escaping, urlencode

I have a C# MVC 3 project that uses `OpenSearch` to search for product. Search is fine if the search word is one word but if I type something like `canned food` then I get `HTTP Error 404.11`. 
I know that one easy way to fix this is set the `allowDoubleEscaping` equals to `true` in `webconfig`. But my friend suggested me to use `escaping url` which would replace the `space` with `%20` (correct me if I am wrong because I am new to this)

I have seen a lot of examples that says to use `UrlPathEncode` but I am not sure where to add this code in my project.

Basically I am just asking how can I make this:

```
localhost:94830/Home/Search/canned food
```

into this

```
localhost:94830/Home/Search/canned%20food
```

or replace space with another character

```
localhost:94830/Home/Search/canned-food
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`System.Uri.EscapeUriString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring.aspx) as follows:

```
Uri.EscapeUriString("double  space") //double%20%20space
```

and as it's also available in "client profile", it's more portable than using `System.Web` APIs.

Comment: Thanks but where do I add this code? I mean what file does this code needs to be in?

Comment: Just pass the search-query through this before you initiate the actual search (or does OpenSearch somehow make this difficult?)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zttxte6w.aspx)

In this example, the string '*ASP.NET Examples*' is encoded as "*ASP.NET+Examples*".

```
Server.UrlEncode("ASP.NET Examples");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found in my case, that I had a JavaScript function that called my ASPX page, and when it builds the URL, I had accidentally put the URL like this:

```
var url = forwardpage + "&t=" + token;
```

As you know, the first parameter in a page request is delmited by ? not &, so a simple typo caused HTTP 404.11.  Instead, it should have been:

```
var url = forwardpage + "?t=" + token;
```