# How to enable double escaping in .net core webapi?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, webapi

I have issue with my webapi.

All commands works fine until in adress i have + or %2B.

When i try to do this, i always getting:

> HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found

I don't have experience in IIS configuration (i am green in it), and don't see any configuration file inside project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964287/http-error-404-11-not-found-double-escape-sequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For cannot use plus symbol in route,this is an IIS issue:

Please look at the following post:

[double escape sequence inside a url : The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739233/double-escape-sequence-inside-a-url-the-request-filtering-module-is-configured)

You need add the following section in your `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration> 
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Result:

[image]

**Note:**

If you **do not have web.config file** in your project,you could follow the steps to create it:

1.Right-click your project->choose `Add`->choose `New Item`:

[image]

2.Search `config` in search bar->choose `Web Configuration File`:

[image]

Comment: But where is that web.config? I Can't find it inside my project.

Comment: Hi @Obyi,check my answer.And remember accept answer in your [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66650060/11398810).

Comment: Thanks! Now i figured out how to fix it!